# Cap transfer rates on shared dirs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares, file-sharing

I have a USB drive on my main machine that every uses and want to know if it is possible to max the amount that can be downloaded off it in terms of Mbit/s as to not slow down my connection to the internet from users who are using it.

Comment: How are this USB drive contents shared? Most probably, you'll need to set up caps and/or rate limiting in the software that facilitates this sharing.

Comment: Just by using the shared option to share the drive over the network to everyone. Where would you find rate limiting?

Comment: It sounds like a different approach to storing this data would be a better option than trying to work out data limiting options.  Could the usb drive not be moved to an alternative machine, or replaced with a NAS (an external drive directly connected to the network without needing a PC)

Comment: @RachelNark: You cannot do what you're asking using built-in Windows tools. And using any other third-party software/hardware for rate-limiting and capping SMB traffic will be more difficult than just switch to a different protocol, and use a dedicated server that supports rate-limiting and or caps (BitTorrent, FTP, etc.)